# Why TypeScript gives the error message Property 'value' does not exist on type 'unknown'?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the below function:

```
myChart.on('click', { targetType: 'axisLabel' }, params => {
      var uri = window.location.hash.replace("#", "");
      this.router.navigate([uri + '/trips', params.value]);
    })
```

This function returns the error message:

```
Property 'value' does not exist on type 'unknown'.
```

The given `params` contains `value`. How do I resolve the error that keeps popping up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a type annotation to `params`. Otherwise the compiler cannot infer its type, and thus cannot know if it actually has the `value` property.

E.g.

```
interface Params {
    value: string
}

myChart.on('click', { targetType: 'axisLabel' }, (params: Params): void => {
    var uri = window.location.hash.replace("#", "");
    this.router.navigate([uri + '/trips', params.value]);
});
```